# How to show article is upvoted/downvoted like reddit after refreshing the webpage?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to create a website that lets users upvote or downvote posts.

Here's my two tables:

```
---------------------------------
| student_id | news_id  | score |
---------------------------------
|    22      |    1     |   1   |
---------------------------------
|    22      |    2     |  -1   |
---------------------------------
|    23       |   2     |  -1   |
---------------------------------
```

Here's my newsfeed table

```
------------------------
| news_id | title      |
------------------------
|    1   |    TitleOne |
------------------------
|    2   |    TitleTwo |
------------------------
```

Here's the code I'm using

```
    <?php $query2 = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM newsfeed ORDER BY date_and_time DESC");
    $query2 -> execute ();
    while($row = $query2 -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $datetime = $row['date_and_time'];
        $datetime = date('F d, M', strtotime ($datetime));
        $title = $row['title'];
        $score = $row['score'];
        $news_id = $row['news_id']; 
   ?>


    <button class="vote upvote-button upvote<?php echo $news_id;?>" id="<?php echo $news_id ; ?>">
    Upvote</button>

    <button class="vote remove-upvote-button remove-upvote<?php echo $news_id ; ?>" id="<?php echo $news_id; ?>">
    Upvoted</button>

    <button class="vote downvote-button downvote<?php echo $news_id;?>" id="<?php echo $news_id; ?>">
    Downvote</button>

    <button class="vote remove-downvote-button remove-downvote<?php echo $news_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $news_id; ?>">
    Downvoted</button> <div class='box2' >

<?php echo $title; ?> </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The code above only displays the first and third button. What I want to do is, when a user clicks the first button (Upvote), and then refreshes the page, the webpage will display the second button (Upvoted). Same with the downvote. If the user clicks the third button then refreshes the page, it will display the fourth button (Downvoted).

For those who will suggest I use Ajax. I already use it and I can already make it work. My problem is really after refreshing the page. I can't find a logical solution to display which button is clicked.

Comment: You have no conditions to display the buttons, so what have you tried?

Comment: Do you store the button click on the server? Why not use Javascript to tell the server what the user is doing, so on refresh you highlight whether the user has clicked the button or not

Comment: @devon I've tried creating another query namely ("SELECT * FROM upvote_connect) then another while loop with an IF statement like this if($student_id>0 && $real_news_id==$news_id &&  $score==1){<button>Upvoted</button>}. It works but the it doubles the number of posts

Comment: @brianlmerritt The first table saves if a user clicks an upvote and downvote if that is what you mean. Can you tell me what JavaScript function I'll need?

Comment: Ajax - I suggest you start with jQuery which makes this a lot easier